# How do I split a branch after a certain commit?

Tags: git, branch

I've added a few commits to the end of the branch, but I've decided that they'd be better off in a separate feature branch.

I could create a branch now and revert the changes in the main branch, but that creates a messy history, and ideally I would like to clean that up before pushing to the remote repository.

Is there a better way to go from:

```
A-B-C-D-E
```

to:

```
A-B-C
     \
      D-E
```

As if I correctly branched at `C` in the first place?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure why everyone wants to do a rebase here.  All you need to do is create a feature branch at your current head, then reset your master back where you want it:

```
git branch feature
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

Comment: Yes, absolutely this. *All that needs to happen* is for a new branch ref to be created, pointing to E, and for the old branch to be reset back to C. No history needs to be rewritten.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create the new branch off `HEAD` [`git checkout`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

   `git checkout master`
   `git checkout -b branch`

   This creates the new branch that holds all commits of `master`
2. Remove the commits `D` and `E` from master with an interactive [`git rebase`](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html):

   `git checkout master`
   `git rebase -i <SHA_A>`

   In the editor that pops up, delete the lines with commits `D` and `E`.
   If you didn't change the editor, it's Vim, so hit <kbd>j</kbd> until you are on the line with commit `D`, then type <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to delete that line. Same with the line of commit `E`. When you're done, type <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> to close the editor.

Done!

A VIM Quick Reference Card could be found here: http://tnerual.eriogerg.free.fr/vim.html

Comment: your master branch and new branch is not on the correct commit point

Comment: Aha, this worked and it's interesting for other potential use-cases, but Karl Bielefeldt's answer wins out for pure simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can checkout the commit (`git checkout sha`) and then branch from there (`git checkout -b newbranch`). I haven't tested this.

**EDIT**: Just realized that you want to move commits after that commit to the new branch. I believe what you'll want to look into is `git rebase`.